# Coefficient of effective chiral Lagrangian of $\pi\pi$ scattering

Tags: field-theory, mathematical-physics, lie-algebra, chirality, sigma-models

I have been suffering from the coefficient in the expansion of chiral lagrangian.
Consider $$L=\frac{F^{2}}{4} \rm{Tr}(\partial_{\mu}U^{\dagger}\partial^{\mu}U),$$
where $$U=\exp(i\frac{\phi}{F}).$$ For $\pi\pi$ scattering,we need the 4 $\pi's$ terms $L^{\phi_{4}}$. To get $L^{\phi_{4}}$,we expand $$U \approx 1+i\frac{\phi}{F}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\phi^{2}}{F^{2}}-\frac{i}{6}\frac{\phi^{3}}{F^{3}}+\frac{1}{24}\frac{\phi^{4}}{F^{4}},$$then I have seen lots of books which state the result of this calculation is $$\frac{1}{48} \rm{Tr}([\phi,\partial_{\mu}\phi][\phi,\partial^{\mu}\phi]),$$ however,I can not see why there is a factor of 3 in the denominator,since if we only consider four $\pi's$ term then only order less than $(\frac{\phi}{F})^{2}$ will survive. Can anyone explain how to do the calculation?

Comment: You don't need the quartic term. Make sure you do this [efficiently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#Statement).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you for your comments. But I still can not figure it out. After we take the derivative of $U$, shouldn't we get $\partial_{\mu}U=\phi_{\mu}(\frac{i}{F}-\frac{\phi}{F^{2}}-\frac{i}{2}\frac{\phi^{2}}{F^{3}})$ since we can cycle the order of the matrix in the trace.Then where are the 1/6 and 1/4 come from? I would appreciate it if you would like to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importantly, observe what you might know, namely the method in the madness of the Lie algebra elements involved,
$$L=\frac{F^{2}}{4} \rm{Tr}(\partial_{\mu}U^{\dagger}\partial^{\mu}U)= \frac{F^{2}}{4} \rm{Tr}(\partial_{\mu}U^{\dagger}U ~~ U^\dagger\partial^{\mu}U)
,$$
where the $\phi$s are Hermitean matrices!

But there is celebrated systematics in the  [operator exponential derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#Statement), to $O(\phi^3)$,
$$
U^\dagger\partial U =    \frac{i}{F} \partial \phi  +  \frac{1}{2F^2} [\phi, \partial \phi]-  \frac{i}{6F^3}[\phi,   [\phi  ,\partial \phi ]]   +...   ~~~\implies \\
\partial U^\dagger ~ U =  - \frac{i}{F} \partial \phi  -  \frac{1}{2F^2} [\phi, \partial \phi]+  \frac{i}{6F^3}[\phi,   [\phi  ,\partial \phi ]]   +...   .
$$
The are each in the Lie Algebra!
Plug these inside the trace, and use its cyclicity to rearrange the commutators.

The quartic term you are seeking comes from the linear times cubic terms, and, of course, the squared quadratic ones,
$$
\frac{F^{2}}{4} \frac{1}{F^4}(1/3-1/4)\rm{Tr} ([\phi,\partial_{\mu}\phi][\phi,\partial^{\mu}\phi]) \\
=\frac{1}{48 F^2} \rm{Tr}([\phi,\partial_{\mu}\phi][\phi,\partial^{\mu}\phi]).$$

Note the surviving quadratic/kinetic term, and the vanishing of the cubic one.

Comment: Thank you！The answer really helps a lot

Comment: But I still wonder,why I just can’t expand the exp and do the calculation as I did above, I still can’t find why I am wrong there

Comment: Your expression is naive! Recall $\phi$ and $\partial \phi$ don't commute , but your curt expansion assumed that... After all, the final answer *relies* on non-commutativity...

Comment: yes，you are right.Thanks again !

Comment: Apologies: I corrected some errors the complacent eye would slide over...